# Prevent glob from selecting a file with a specific file name

Tags: php, glob

I have a folder with 5 html files. The files are called:

- page-1.html
- page-2.html
- page-hello.html
- page-32.html
- yo-page-text.html

I wish to use glob function to return an array with only the files formatted: "page[number 0 - 1000]".
So essentially I wish the glob function to return the following pages from the example above:

- page-1.html
- page-2.html
- page-32.html

**This is the code that I have managed to write so far:**

```php
<?php
    $directory = "testfolder/";
    foreach (glob($directory . "page-*.html") as $filename) {
        echo basename($filename);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glob` pattern is not as flexible as RegEx, so unless someone has some other magic, you can filter after the glob:

```
$files = preg_grep('/page-[0-9]+\.html/', glob($directory . '*.*'));
```

If the `glob` pattern supported repetition `+` then it would be easy.  Bash and Korn shells offer it with `+([0-9])` but PHP doesn't.

You could also check for one number and trust that what follows matched by `*` will be numbers with: `glob($directory . 'page-[0-9]*.html')`, but this could match `page-0-hello.html` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This seems to have answered all of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your code works and that you get the `basename` of the files:

```
$name = basename($filename); //do not echo the basename
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
  $trname = "page-$i";
  if ($name == $trname) {
    echo "$name";
  }
}
```

Put one of these codes inside the `foreach` and get rid of `echo basename($filename);`. I'd recommend using the second one as nesting loops may prove to be a problem.

> **Note**: This code can only work if your one works.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**:
My guess id that you want to do something (not echoing) the names, in which case:

```
function foo(bar) {
  $arr = array();
  $name = basename($filename);
  $name = str_replace("page-", "", $name);
  if (intval($name) < 1000 && intval($name) >= 0) {
    $arr[] = $name;
  }
}
```

Then, you can call on the function this way:

```
function foo() {
$arr = array();
$directory = "testfolder/";
foreach (glob($directory . "page-*.html") as $filename) {
  $name = basename($filename);
  $name = str_replace("page-", "", $name);
  if (intval($name) < 1000 && intval($name) >= 0) {
    $arr[] = $name;
  }
}
}
$bar = foo();
foreach ($bar as $obj) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This seems like a good solution. Do you know if it is possible to solve my issue though changing the wildcard formatting? Something along the lines of: `glob($directory . "page-[1-9999]*.html")`, etc?

Comment: Wildcard formatting? I'm not sure how you could do that, but what's the problem with loops? Or is it that you don't want to nest loops?

Comment: I will accept your answer as it solves my issue. However, I thought that there was another way to check for the filename through formatting the wildcard. What I mean with that is that this section of the code `. "page-*.html"` allows me to specify what files that should be added to the array.